# How to set-up Xcode signing provisions

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, apple-developer-account

So I recently got hired as a react native developer, and they already have an app published on the App Store. So I am just trying to set-up the app in development mode on my Mac.

I already have an apple developer account, but when I open up Xcode, and have my developer account under signing & capabilities, I receive two errors:

```
The app identifier "com.theapp.theapp" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
```

and:

```
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.theapp.theapp'.
```

What do I need to configure? or do I have to use the specific account?

Comment: Has your developer account been added to the company's Apple Developer account?

Comment: So I built the app, and it ran successfully. Those errors however are still present but I guess I will just ignore them for now. Also, this might have to be a separate question, but when I run the app, the app runs successfully, except I am unable to see any images. Any ideas? Thanks for the respone

Comment: So I initially ran the app on the ios simulator, and everthing more or less works fine, but when i try using my physical device, the error halts the build. And to answer your question, no, my developer account has not been added to the companys apple developer account. Would this fix the issue you think? Thanks

Comment: If you you're added to the developer account and you add your device id to the certificate, you'll be able to build on the device.